# Building Customer Service Applications

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I read manual "[Chapter 11: Building Customer Service Applications for the Right Situations (Real World SharePoint 2010)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg193964%28v=office.14%29.aspx)". Build and install example code on test farm.

But the service only run on one server.

[image]

Advise idea how to run CacheService on second server?

Comment: Exemple code: http://media.wiley.com/product_ancillary/35/04705971/DOWNLOAD/Chapter11_code.zip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve my problem by writing PowerShell Comand:

```
[Cmdlet(VerbsCommon.Add, "CalcServiceInstance", SupportsShouldProcess = true)]
public class AddCaclServiceInstance : SPCmdlet
{
    private SPServer _server;

    [Parameter()]
    public SPServer Server{
        get{return _server;}
        set{_server = value;}
    }

    protected override bool RequireUserFarmAdmin()
    {
        return true;
    }

    protected override void InternalProcessRecord()
    {
        if (_server == null)
        {
            _server = SPServer.Local;
        }
        if ((SPPersistedObject)null == (SPPersistedObject)_server)
        {
            this.WriteError((Exception)new InvalidOperationException("Server not found."), ErrorCategory.ObjectNotFound, (object)this);
            this.SkipProcessCurrentRecord();
        }
        CalcService service = SPFarm.Local.Services.GetValue<CalcService>();
        if ((SPPersistedObject)null == (SPPersistedObject)service)
        {
            service = new CalcService(SPFarm.Local);
            service.Update(true);
            service.Provision();
        }
        if ((SPPersistedObject)null != (SPPersistedObject)_server.ServiceInstances.GetValue<CalcServiceInstance>(string.Empty))
            this.SkipProcessCurrentRecord();
        CalcServiceInstance calcServiceInstance = new CalcServiceInstance(_server, service);
        _server.ServiceInstances.Ensure((SPServiceInstance)calcServiceInstance);
        calcServiceInstance.Provision();
        calcServiceInstance.Update();
    }
}
```

And using on SharePoint server:

```
$server = Get-SPServer "APP-02"    
Add-CalcServiceInstance -Server $server
```